# Converting 10.5 mxd to 10.4 without ArcMap 10.5?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Is there any way to convert a 10.5 mxd to 10.4 without having 10.5 on the system?

I know ArcCatalog 10.4 - Data Sources allows me to see the datasets in the 10.5 mxd but then I don't have access to the layout/symbology etc.

All the processes I can find require 10.5 to be installed to use arcpy or save-as in arcmap.

Comment: "Is there any way to convert a 10.5 mxd to 10.4 without having 10.5 on the system?". No there isn't. You need to use 10.5 (or later) to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ArcGIS Desktop Help on [Saving to previous versions of ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/map/working-with-arcmap/saving-a-map.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_47EBF84D55D545B68A33CB778A653481) it says:

> In most cases, after you open and save an existing map document (.mxd
>   file), the map can no longer be opened with earlier versions of ArcGIS
>   because it will now reflect the new functionality. Similarly, new
>   documents cannot be opened in earlier versions of the software;
>   however, you can use the **Save A Copy** command to make a copy of a
>   map document so you can open and work with it in previous versions of
>   ArcGIS. Note that documents from ArcGIS 10.1, 10.2, and related
>   releases, such as 10.2.1, are directly compatible with each other;
>   ArcGIS 9.0 and 9.1 documents are also compatible with each other.

Conquently, I think you need to open your 10.5 MXD at 10.5 or later and save it to a 10.4 MXD.  I am not aware of any earlier ArcGIS version or non-ArcGIS way to do it.

There is an existing ArcGIS Idea titled [Backward/Forward Compatibility](https://community.esri.com/ideas/11608) which you may wish to vote for, if you have not already.

Comment: Thanks - the last time I looked at it was about 4 years ago (the idea in the link was from 2015...) so I was hoping that ESRI had a solution by know. I voted up the idea.